# Adding title to ggsurvplot

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I would like to add title to ggsurvplot. Here is my code:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data =lung, main = "This is title")
```

It generates plot, but without title. If add `risk.table = TRUE`, then I get title on top of risk table, but not the main plot.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data =lung, main = "This is title", 
           risk.table = TRUE)
```

[image: ggsurvplot title]

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the title with `title =` , not with `main =`.

```
ggsurvplot(fit, data =lung, title = "This is title", 
           risk.table = TRUE)
```

[Output_Link_Here as I guess I'm too new to embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcOP0.jpg)

Comment: How did you get the answer?

Comment: The documentation is actually a bit messed up in a few places where it does indeed say 'main' for the main title.  Documentation here seems correct: http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/survminer/reference/ggsurvplot.html

Comment: For example...this shows 'main' instead of 'title': https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survminer/versions/0.2.4/topics/ggsurvplot

Comment: Thank you again, do you by any chance know how labels are ordered. I cannot seem to figure out.

Comment: Which labels do you mean?

Comment: In this case, I would like to replace `sex = 1` and `sex = 2`

Answer (score 3):

And if you want to center the title and change the font type as bold and/or make other changes to the ggplot theme, use `+ theme()`:

```
ggtheme = theme_minimal() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))
```

Comment: adding the theme() does not seem to work. Running the same code:  
     fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
     p <- ggsurvplot(fit, data =lung, title = "This is title", 
           risk.table = TRUE, ggtheme = theme_minimal())
     p + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"))

I get the error: "Error in p + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: Turns out you are meant to use p$plot + theme() for it to work with ggsurvplot.